# Is a medical form required for a short-term visit to South Africa for a conference?

Tags: india, airports, health, south-africa

I am flying to South Africa in few days. I have a valid short-term visa (20 days) . I saw this just now http://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/india/conferences.html and below that http://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/india/pdf/Medical_form_301214.pdf . I swear I didn't see this before, it wasn't there, probably has come after 1st June 2016. Now is it imperative that I get this filled by a physician and could I be denied entry at the airport (either in CPT,SA or in India before boarding the aircraft) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That form appears to only be required for other types of visas.

On the [page](http://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/india/conferences.html) for short-term visas for "conferences," the "documents required" tab lists the documents you needed to submit. It does not list a medical report. In contrast, the [page](http://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/india/study-visa.html) for a long-term study visa does state that both a medical report and a radiological report (to confirm that you don't have TB) are required.

We can also [consult Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=ZA&selDest=Mexico&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point(s)%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the system the airline will use to determine what documents are required. It states that a visa is required, which you already have, but does not indicate any medical form is needed. The only health-related requirement is that "Passengers who have visited Guinea, Liberia or Sierra Leone are subject to screening and health checks."